# Fullpage.js OnLeave firing twice when return false in all browsers but Chrome

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I have this code:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    scrollingSpeed: 500,
    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
        if(nextIndex == 2){
                alert('test');
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

In Chrome the alert is occurring once, but in Firefox and IE it seems to be occurring twice. Any insight into why this is happening would be SUPER appreciated!

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/856/

Thanks!

Comment: i found this link https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/759 describing the same problem, it's reported as fixed in 2.3.5 but looking at your problem, doesn't seem like it is. If you add 'autoScrolling:true' to your fiddle the problem goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in fullPage.js related with the way it handles the mouse events:

```
function addMouseWheelHandler() {
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener('mousewheel', MouseWheelHandler, false); //IE9, Chrome, Safari, Oper
        document.addEventListener('wheel', MouseWheelHandler, false); //Firefox

    // [[[[[[[ THE ISSUE IS HERE ]]]]]]]
        document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', MouseWheelHandler, false); //Old Firefox 
    } else {
        document.attachEvent('onmousewheel', MouseWheelHandler); //IE 6/7/8
    }
}
```

It seems Firefox is listening to both events, `wheel` and `DOMMouseScroll`. You can check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jotswekc/).
Try removing the "Old firefox" event handler (`DOMMouseScroll`) and you'll see how it only fires one now.

Feel free to open an issue [in fullpage.js repository](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues) reporting it.

Comment: I just tried in both Firefox and Chrome. Firefox is logging 1 event per scroll, while Firefox is logging 2 per scroll.

Comment: Awesome, that does fix it in Firefox for me. Internet Explorer is still logging twice, any idea how that could be fixed?

Comment: Accept this answer and open a new one please.

Comment: The question doesn't specify Firefox, it's the same issue still, just for IE.

Comment: I'll take a look at it for the next release. Meanwhile read [this answer](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/1244#issuecomment-140342305).

Comment: Detecting the event model in that ways seems like the route to go. Thanks a bunch!